# NodeJs SQL Server Connection

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect my NodeJs Server to MS SQL Server but I am getting an error -  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Here is my configuration:

On db.js file:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const config = {
    server: 'EUDIN-F3-OFFSHO\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'TodoDb',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
}

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)

module.exports = pool;
```

On my get todos model file:

```
const pool = require('../_database/db');

const getTodosModel = async () => {

    const query = `select * from todo_list`;

    try {
        await pool.connect()
        const response = await pool.request().query(query)
        console.log('success', response)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('getTodosModel says: ', error.message)
    }
}

module.exports = getTodosModel;
```

Error that I get:
Error: getTodosModel says:  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Solution I tried:

- Adding data source on User Dsn and System Dsn on ODCB Data Source Administrator (still did not worked)